# How to pipe a 'yes' or 'y' into a program while invoked with 'sudo' in bash?

Tags: sudo, pipe, yes

How to pipe a `Y` or `yes` to a program while invoking with `sudo`?

We can type like this

```
yes | command
yes | yum update
```

How to pipe the `y` from `yes` into a program via `sudo` like the following?

```
yes| sudo command
```

The `y` from `yes` is be passed into `command` and should go into `sudo` and `sudo` shall ask for password normally. How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/) reads the password from the terminal directly, not from its standard input, unless the `-S` option is used. Thus

```
yes | sudo command
```

should prompt for the password (if necessary), without reading from `yes`, then run `command` as root with its standard input fed from `yes`’s standard output.

If that doesn’t work, you can run the whole pipeline under `sudo` using something like

```
sudo sh -c "yes | command"
```